# how to create a team leaderboard with info from 4 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

This is tricky, I have been tasked with creating an team leader board where individuals complete tasks for a score. The score is defined in the table "station" and every time a user completes a task- a post is created in the posts table with the id of the station and their RFID (radio frequency ID). There is a team table which defines the team name.

i need a way to get the sum of all the post scores (joined points from stations table) a teams members have participated in.

The result should be sorted be team score and look something like if we have 4 teams with 4 members who participated in 4 events- whats the total score for each team

```
Team name one (Teams.name) | score

Team name two (Teams.name) | score

Team name three (Teams.name) | score
```

The tables -

```
CREATE TABLE `posts` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rfid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `station_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=11 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Table structure for table `stations`

```
CREATE TABLE `stations` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `points` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `logic` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1023 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Table structure for table `teams`

```
CREATE TABLE `teams` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;

-- --------------------------------------------------------
```

Table structure for table `users`

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `rfid` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `team` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `quiz_score` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;
```

I have created an query for an individual leaderboard-

```
SELECT users.first_name, users.last_name, posts.rfid, sum(stations.points) score 
FROM posts 
JOIN users ON posts.rfid = users.rfid  
JOIN stations ON posts.station_id = stations.id  
GROUP BY posts.rfid 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 0 , 100
```

this is what i have got so far for the team one

```
SELECT name, (SELECT sum(stations.points) score FROM posts 
      JOIN users ON posts.rfid = users.rfid 
      JOIN stations ON posts.station_id = stations.id  
  WHERE users.team = teams.id 
      GROUP BY posts.rfid) team_score FROM teams

//subquery returns more than one row
```

I think this might be the correct answer

```
SELECT name, 
    (SELECT sum(stations.points) score FROM posts
         JOIN users ON posts.rfid = users.rfid 
         JOIN stations ON posts.station_id = stations.id  
      WHERE users.team = teams.id ) team_score 
  FROM teams
```

Comment: `but i am stuck on this team one` so what exactly is wrong with it?

Comment: i have updated the question with what i have got so far- subquery returns more than one row

Comment: is there an sqlfiddle somewhere, and desired result?